# Grakn server stop takes too much time

Tags: vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

I'm trying to stop Grakn server but it doesn't stop. When I query `status`, it says both server and storage are running.

[image: screenshot]

I thought it's related with [this issue](https://github.com/graknlabs/grakn/issues/4126). However this issue is solved long before.

I did some operations like insert, match, delete with Python client. Is it possible one of them didn't close well?

I can't run any query on Python client or console now, it gives this error:

```
Unable to create connection to Grakn instance at localhost:48555
Cause: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException
UNAVAILABLE: io exception
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the server has actually stopped but the terminal process doesn't know about it.

Grakn Core 1.8 runs as a Java process. You can check if there is a server instance by running:

```
jps
```

If there is a Grakn instance, it will be named `GraknServer`, and you can force quit it if necessary using `kill`.

After that you can restart Grakn using `./grakn server start` as normal.

Comment: Yep. it works. `jps` shows pid as well, which makes it easier for me to kill with pid.